# After filtering, how to select and remove visible rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, worksheet

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$1464").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="promo"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$1464").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="="
Rows("2:2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

I would like to select the visible rows after filtering. I read up some post which uses .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) but I not sure how to amend my existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way (after filtering):

```
' Update: don't select the header
Activesheet.Range("$A$2:$O$1464").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: I tried replacing my last 2 line with your code. It shows compile error: Expected: list separator or

Comment: It kinda work but my column header got delete as well. Anyway to delete 2nd row onwards?

Answer (score -1):

```
'Put after this to your filter code
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Range("A1:A1464")) > 1 then
Range("$A$2:$A$1464").EntireRow.Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
else
Msgbox "Criteria not found"
end if
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21464478)